# Is there a way to prevent duplicate code in r?

Tags: r

I have list named `lst`. in `lst1` and `lst2` I have separated `lst` by gender.

```
iteration1 <- list(year1 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(1,2,2,1)
,weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)),
 year2 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13,10,10), district=c(1,2,3,4,2,1),gender=c(1,2,2,1,1,1),weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1,12.2,13.1)))

iteration2 <- list(year1 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(2,2,1,1)
,weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)),
 year2 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13,13,13,12), district=c(1,2,3,4,1,3,3),gender=c(2,2,1,1,2,2,2),weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1,10.9,11.9,15.1)))

iteration3 <- list(year1 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(2,2,1,1)
,weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)),
 year2 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13,10,10,11,12), district=c(1,2,3,4,4,3,2,2),gender=c(2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2),weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1,13.5,12.8,13.9,14.9)))

lst <- list(iteration1 = iteration1, iteration2 = iteration2, iteration3= iteration3  )

lst1 <- map(lst, ~ map(., filter, gender == 1))
lst2 <- map(lst, ~ map(., filter, gender == 2))
```

in the code below, I have weighted `lst1` and `lst2` and in `mean1` and `mean2` I got mean of each iteration. for doing my purpose, I had to repeat `ans` and `mean` two times.Is there a way to prevent duplicate code  ?

```
ans1<- rbindlist(
  lapply(lst1, function(x) 
    as.data.table(
      questionr::wtd.table(x = x[["year2"]]$district, 
                           y = x[["year2"]]$age,
                           weights = x[["year2"]]$weight) ) ),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )

ans2<- rbindlist(
  lapply(lst2, function(x) 
    as.data.table(
      questionr::wtd.table(x = x[["year2"]]$district, 
                           y = x[["year2"]]$age,
                           weights = x[["year2"]]$weight) ) ),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )

mean1<-ans1[, .(n = .N,
             mean = mean(N, na.rm = TRUE)),
         by = .(district = V1, age = V2)]

mean2<-ans2[, .(n = .N,
             mean = mean(N, na.rm = TRUE)),
         by = .(district = V1, age = V2)]


mean1$gender<- 1
mean2$gender<- 2
popmean<- rbind(mean2,mean1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way using `dplyr` and `purrr` library.

- Combine the list in one dataframe and filter for only `'year2'` rows.
- For each iteration and gender value calculate `questionr::wtd.table` and combine the results in one dataframe,
- Calculate number of rows and average for each `district`, `age` and `gender`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map_df(lst, ~bind_rows(.x, .id = 'year'), .id = 'iter') %>%
  filter(year == 'year2') %>%
  group_split(iter, gender) %>%
  map_df(~with(.x, questionr::wtd.table(x = district, y = age,weights = weight)) %>%
        as.data.frame %>%
          mutate(gender = first(.x$gender))) %>%
  group_by(district = Var1, Age = Var2 , gender) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), 
            mean = mean(Freq, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup

# A tibble: 28 x 5
#  district Age   gender     n  mean
#   <fct>    <fct>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>
# 1 1        10         1     1  25.3
# 2 1        10         2     2  12.2
# 3 1        13         1     1   0  
# 4 1        13         2     1  10.9
# 5 1        11         2     2   0  
# 6 1        12         2     2   0  
# 7 2        10         1     1  12.2
# 8 2        10         2     2   0  
# 9 2        13         1     2   0  
#10 2        13         2     1   0  
# … with 18 more rows
```

Comment: please see my new question `how to avoid duplicate a code for one output`