# how to avoid duplicate a code for one output

Tags: r

I  have posted this question one time and  got an answer . but this time
I have extended my question and that is why I ask this question again .in my new question, I want to merge `ans1` with `ans2` and finally get `final`. Not that for my desired output ,`final`, there is no need to `mean1` and `mean2` just `ans1` and `ans2`.
in `lst1` and `lst2` I have separated `lst` by gender. my desired output is estimating different confidence interval which I have in `final`.

```
iteration1 <- list(year1 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(1,2,2,1)
,weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)),
 year2 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13,10,10), district=c(1,2,3,4,2,1),gender=c(1,2,2,1,1,1),weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1,12.2,13.1)))

iteration2 <- list(year1 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(2,2,1,1)
,weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)),
 year2 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13,13,13,12), district=c(1,2,3,4,1,3,3),gender=c(2,2,1,1,2,2,2),weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1,10.9,11.9,15.1)))

iteration3 <- list(year1 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13), district=c(1,2,3,4),gender=c(2,2,1,1)
,weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1)),
 year2 =data.frame(age=c(10,11,12,13,10,10,11,12), district=c(1,2,3,4,4,3,2,2),gender=c(2,2,1,1,2,2,1,2),weight=c(12.2,11.3,11.2,10.1,13.5,12.8,13.9,14.9)))

lst <- list(iteration1 = iteration1, iteration2 = iteration2, iteration3= iteration3  )

lst1 <- map(lst, ~ map(., filter, gender == 1))
lst2 <- map(lst, ~ map(., filter, gender == 2))
```

in the code below, I have weighted `lst1` and `lst2` . for doing my purpose, I had to repeat code  two times   .Is there a way to prevent duplicate code and merge `res1` with `res2` ?

```
ans1<- rbindlist(
  lapply(lst1, function(x) 
    as.data.table(
      questionr::wtd.table(x = x[["year2"]]$district, 
                           y = x[["year2"]]$age,
                           weights = x[["year2"]]$weight) ) ),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )

ans2<- rbindlist(
  lapply(lst2, function(x) 
    as.data.table(
      questionr::wtd.table(x = x[["year2"]]$district, 
                           y = x[["year2"]]$age,
                           weights = x[["year2"]]$weight) ) ),
  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE )

mean1<-ans1[, .(n = .N,
             mean = mean(N, na.rm = TRUE)),
         by = .(district = V1, age = V2)]

mean2<-ans2[, .(n = .N,
             mean = mean(N, na.rm = TRUE)),
         by = .(district = V1, age = V2)]


mean1$gender<- 1
mean2$gender<- 2
popmean<- rbind(mean2,mean1)




ci <- function(x, conf =0.95){
  lo <- (1 - conf)/2
  up <- 1 - lo
  qq <- qnorm(c(lo, up), mean(x), sd(x))
  c(lower = qq[1], upper = qq[2])
}

confLevels <- c(0.80, 0.90, 0.95)
res1 <- lapply(confLevels, function(x){
  agg <- aggregate(N ~ V1 + V2, ans1, ci, conf = x)
  agg <- cbind(agg[-ncol(agg)], agg[[ncol(agg)]])
  names(agg)[3:4] <- paste(names(agg)[3:4], x, sep = ".")
  agg
  
})
re1<- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y), res1)


res2 <- lapply(confLevels, function(x){
  agg <- aggregate(N ~ V1 + V2, ans2, ci, conf = x)
  agg <- cbind(agg[-ncol(agg)], agg[[ncol(agg)]])
  names(agg)[3:4] <- paste(names(agg)[3:4], x, sep = ".")
  agg
  
})
re2<- Reduce(function(x, y) merge(x, y), res2)
re1$gender=1
re2$gender=2
final<- rbind(re1,re2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a dataframe/tibble as an output from the function `ci`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ci <- function(x, conf =0.95){

  lo <- (1 - conf)/2
  up <- 1 - lo
  qq <- qnorm(c(lo, up), mean(x), sd(x))
  tibble(!!paste0('lower.', conf) := qq[1], 
         !!paste0('upper.', conf) := qq[2])
}
```

Store the output from the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68140652/3962914) in `result` and you can do -

```
confLevels <- c(0.80, 0.90, 0.95)

map(confLevels, ~result %>%
  group_by(district, Age, gender) %>%
  summarise(data = list(ci(mean, .x)), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  unnest(data) %>% data.frame) %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = c("district", "Age", "gender"))
```

Comment: Actually that is because my answer does not generate duplicate values. If you check `ans1` (or `ans2`) there are some duplicate rows. If you keep only the unique ones `ans1 <- unique(ans1)` and run your code you'll get `NA`s as well with your answer.

Comment: So what should I do?

Comment: Is this the real data that you are applying code to?

Comment: No it is a sample data, my real data is different

Comment: Can you try the answer on your real data? I am hoping this would not be the case in the real data.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to include in `Age` in `group_by`. If you keep `group_by(district, gender) %>%` and do the same change in join `reduce(inner_join, by = c("district", "gender"))`. You get some values but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks but I need age to be included